# MySql date range search with month and day (any year)

Tags: mysql

For example, if i have search string "2017-12-14" then i need to find all rows that matches 7-day range: "%-12-11", "%-12-12", "%-12-13", "%-12-14", "%-12-15", "%-12-16", "%-12-17".

Is it possible to do with MySql only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select same day cross years you can use following trick.

1. get the list of last 7 days/1 week `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK`
2. get the `DAYOFYEAR` of that days
3. search the database for all values of the same day in year

.

```
SELECT * FROM timevalues
WHERE DAYOFYEAR(timefield) IN (
  SELECT DAYOFYEAR(timefield)
  FROM timevalues
  WHERE DATE(timefield) BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND NOW()
  )
;
```

Note: Leap year is not taken into calculation!
According to my brief investigation according to the leap year it would be easier to extend the SQL query with tolerance of 1 day, ie to use `- INTERVAL 8 DAY` instead of `7` and then control the validity of the day outside the database during processing the data in a loop.

Comment: Great! And please accept the answer: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

The function you are looking for is `+/- INTERVAL expr unit`. See [MySQL Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

So to get 7 days back use `- INTERVAL 7 DAY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE DATE(timefield) BETWEEN '2017-12-14' - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND '2017-12-14'
```

According to your example would be enough to use `-INTERVAL 1 WEEK`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE DATE(timefield) BETWEEN '2017-12-14' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND '2017-12-14'
```

And [List of all possible units](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

> MICROSECOND SECOND MINUTE HOUR DAY WEEK MONTH QUARTER YEAR
>   SECOND_MICROSECOND MINUTE_MICROSECOND MINUTE_SECOND HOUR_MICROSECOND
>   HOUR_SECOND HOUR_MINUTE DAY_MICROSECOND DAY_SECOND DAY_MINUTE DAY_HOUR
>   YEAR_MONTH

Comment: the subject is a little complicated than this. Your example show rows with only the given year. I need to find rows that matches that 1 week interval (month-day) with all years.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I did not noticed it in the title of the question. I read only the description..